# "Generate constructor" and "add parameters" commmand templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to alter code generated by "Generate Constructor" and "Add parameter to constructor" commands? I need to add some basic null checks in there.

Visual Studio 2022. Cursor is placed on property name.

[image]
[image]

Searched in snippets, but couldn't find template with this command.

Comment: What major/minor version of Visual Studio do you have installed? If I right click on a class and select "Quick actions and Refactoring (CTRL + `.`), when I select "Generate constructor...", I get prompted to selected the parameters I wish and additionally there is a checkbox to add null checks. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1YpF.png

Comment: I place cursor on property name, so its more in  context of property. I get same dialog as you when cursor is in any other place in class